# How do I fix this error when trying to schedule daily emails on python?

Tags: python, automation

I'm trying to send a data frame to myself daily via email. I've gotten this far and everything works but when I try to send it at a specific time I get this error

'the first argument must be callable' - referencing the fact that I'm calling a function within the parentheses.

Any ways to fix this? Also now that I have this set up, if I close my program, will it continue to run the script so that it executes daily?

Thanks,

```
def email_new(df):
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message['Subject'] = "Subject"
    message['From'] = 'email@outlook.com'
    message['To'] = 'email@gmail.com'
    
    html = MIMEText(df.to_html(index=False), "html")
    message.attach(html)
    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.office365.com", 587) as server:
        server.starttls()
        server.login('email@outlook.com','password')
        server.sendmail('email@outlook.com', 'email.edu', message.as_string())


        
schedule.every().day.at('17:40').do(email_new(df))



while True: 
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Closing your program would stop the schedule from running since it would never call `schedule.run_pending()` (and actually, the schedule just wouldn't exist any more). If you want your script to run every day at a certain time then it might be best to look at running it using your system scheduler such as cron or the windows task scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

`do()` takes the arguments to pass to the function in a second parameter:

```
schedule.every().day.at('17:40').do(email_new,df)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this `.do` method, but in general, you can partially instantiate your `email_new` function using `functools.partial`. In this way, you can just pass your partially instantiated `email_new` function directly to the `.do` method.

Let's start with a toy example:

```py
from functools import partial


def add_two_numbers(x, y):
    return x + y

add_5_10 = partial(add_two_numbers, 5, 10)
print(add_5_10())  # 15
```

Now with your example:

```py
from functools import partial


def email_new(df):
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message['Subject'] = "Subject"
    message['From'] = 'email@outlook.com'
    message['To'] = 'email@gmail.com'
    
    html = MIMEText(df.to_html(index=False), "html")
    message.attach(html)
    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.office365.com", 587) as server:
        server.starttls()
        server.login('email@outlook.com','password')
        server.sendmail('email@outlook.com', 'email.edu', message.as_string())


email_new_df = partial(email_new, df)
schedule.every().day.at('17:40').do(email_new_df)

while True: 
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

As for scheduling while you're away from your laptop, I'd recommend learning about [Cron Jobs](https://ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/). However, your laptop must be awake and able to perform the process. In this case, perhaps a remote computer or a Raspberry Pi might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

See the schedule module examples for passing arguments to your function here: https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#pass-arguments-to-a-job

You pass arguments for your function as additional parameters to the `do` method. For your schedule you would use

```
schedule.every().day.at('17:40').do(email_new, df)
```